# Python telegram bot deployed on heroku failed to stablish connection

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to deploy a simple python telegram bot to heroku. It web-crawls 'http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/' using requests and bs4, and extracts synonyms for that word. But once uploaded to the server it is unable to stablish connection, it raises the following exception

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.wordreference.com', port=80): Max retries
exceeded with url: /sinonimos/Calor (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x7fb3aeed80b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network
 is unreachable',))
```

It works perfectly executed locally. I tried to crawl other urls aswell on heroku and it just works fine. So I guess that if it was a port-binding issue, I'd had get a response for other urls. I tried using a free proxy server in case free accounts had limitations to certain addresses as shown here

```
    proxies = {'http': 'http:/40.141.163.122:8080'}

page='http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/{}'.format(word)
r = requests.get(page,proxies=proxies)
```

It worked for a while, and then stopped, not raising any exceptions to the logs. I contacted Heroku support, but they didn't reply yet, so if anyone can shine some light on the issue so I stop flying in the dark it'd be appreciated

Comment: How long is "a while" before it stopped? How are you running your process? Via a one-off dyno? Heroku dynos aren't designed for long-running processes. They restart at least once per day.

Comment: Yes,via a one-off dyno. And it was a matter of  minutes. When it stopped working,  I restarted it with no luck